# text-file manipulation in bash

Tags: bash

so I have this file that contains some data. that I use to create a graph using graphviz.
the problem is that I need to open a file and put a curly braces at the end and beginning of the file. I also write digraph before the opening braces.

than run my script to create the graph.

```
cat data.txt | dot -Tpng > image.png
```

The problem is that I would like to automate the first step and add `digraph {` at the begining and `}`  at the end withing my script that create the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You could execute your commands using a list `{…}`:

```
{ echo 'digraph {'; cat data.txt; echo '}'; } | dot -Tpng > image.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
printf 'digraph {\n}\n' | sed '1r data.txt' | dot -Tpng > image.png
```

Rather than adding text around your files contents, you inject your files contents into the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try Awk.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { print "digraph (" }
    1
    END { print ")" }' data.txt |
dot -Tpng > image.png
```

`1` is a simple Awk shorthand for `{ print }`.
The `cat` was not strictly necessary,

Answer (score 0):

You can just feed your data to echo, loading data.text via ``s.   In a modern shell you can use the $() construct as well.

One echo process, one cat process, one dot process:

```
echo digraph {`cat data.text`} | dot -Tpng > image.png
```